# What does the state (Active, Req, Done) column in tcpmon mean?

Tags: http, tcp, tcpmon

I've had no luck at all getting information regarding tcpmon's displayed fields.

In particular, I'm confused by the 'State' column which moves from Active->Req->Done over the course of a transmission.  Does anybody understand precisely what each of these three states mean?

I ask because I seem to suffer from intermittent hangs, where a communication is left in the 'Req' state.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I've not used tcpmon, but perhaps consider Wireshark? This will enable looking at the individual TCP packets, if desired, and will highlight certain issues such as bad handshakes or missing packets, etc.

Comment: I've now tried running it through wire shark, and although I'm certainly no expert on network traffic, it would appear that everything is good.  I can see no difference between the responses that behave as expected, and those that result in a hung 'Req' state.  This is firming up my suspicions that there is an issue in soap over http using axis2.  I'm too much of a noob to really have an opinion there.

Answer (score 0):

I just took a peak at the [source code](http://ws.apache.org/tcpmon/source-repository.html) for tcpmon, and I think I understand what the states mean.

- **Active**: a socket has been created, but nothing has been read or written over the socket
- **Req**: data is being sent over the socket
- **Done**: the socket has been closed

My guess is that there is a bug in tcpmon that hangs in the `Req` state when it never closes the socket properly. I know there was such a bug in an older version, as indicated by a comment in their source code:

```
// Only loop as long as the connection to the target
// machine is available - once that's gone we can stop.
// The old way, loop until both are closed, left us
// looping forever since no one closed the 1st one.
```

This is probably overkill for what you want to know, but you can find the logic they use to set the state column in the files [`RawSender.java`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/webservices/tcpmon/trunk/modules/tcpmon-core/src/main/java/org/apache/ws/commons/tcpmon/core/ui/RawSender.java?view=markup) and [`Connection.java`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/webservices/tcpmon/trunk/modules/tcpmon-core/src/main/java/org/apache/ws/commons/tcpmon/core/engine/Connection.java?view=markup).